# Existence of $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

We know that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$. I want to know that if $E[X^2]$ exists,  does it guarantees then $E[X]$ will also exist?

Comment: You might want to take a look at following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy More specifically, this is [Lyapunov's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511778/lyapunovs-inequality-in-probability/2707171#:~:text=Taking%20Z%3D%7CX%7Cs,%E2%88%9E%20to%20apply%20the%20inequality%20.) which is indeed a direct consequence of Holder's inequality (for which, in turn, Cauchy-Schwarz is a particular case).

Answer (score 2):

$0\le |X| \le \max(1,X^2) \le 1+X^2$ so $0 \le E[|X|] \le 1+ E[X^2]$,

meaning that if $E[X^2]$ is finite then so too are $E[|X|]$ and $E[X]$

Comment: It is against the site's rules to answer such questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1